# Python two nested loops: why the second loop runs only once?

Tags: python, loops

I used python 2.7 to loop two lists, hoping that for every element in 'mcode.txt', if it exists in a line in 'info.txt', then it prints the element in 'mcode.txt' and a part of the line in 'info.txt'.

the 'mcode.txt' looks like this:

```
M010000000000316660
M010000000000439672
M010000000000346627
M010000000000265328
```

the 'info.txt' looks like this:

```
H05-01-001A M010000000000439672
H05-01-002A M010000000000316660
H05-01-003A M010000000000346627
H05-01-004A M010000000000265328
```

Here's my code.

```
import re
with open('mcode.txt') as mcodetext:
    with open('info.txt') as infotext:
        for mcode in mcodetext:
            for info in infotext:
                if mcode in info:
                    location = re.findall('(H..........)',info)
                    print mcode,location
```

output:

```
M010000000000316660
['H05-01-002A']
```

desired output:

```
M010000000000316660
['H05-01-002A']
M010000000000439672
['H05-01-001A']
M010000000000346627
['H05-01-003A']
M010000000000265328
['H05-01-004A']
```

I've tried adding 'print' after different lines to see where exactly went wrong. It seems like the second loop runs only once and then stops.

I would really appreciate it if you could let me know how to work the code properly. Many thanks!

Comment: Files do not re-wind to the start automatically. You'd have to use `infotext.seek(0)` before looping over `infotext`. You probably want to avoid repeated reading from a file however, as that is *slow*.

Comment: wow thank you!!! that worked! and sorry for not being able to find the duplicate of this question. :)